# Mattermost metadata priority

Tags: mattermost

I have some troubles with setting priority on my BOT message

Here is my payload

`{"channel": "@$user", "text": "Hi! Your Reminder is: $text", "metadata": {"priority":{"priority": "Urgent"}}}`

But message is still with no labels of priority...

sending it with web-hook into direct message (I guess payload structure on hooks the same as API)

Any advices ?

Answer (score 0):

Accepted values are `urgent` and `important`, all lowercase, so:

```
{"priority":{"priority": "urgent"}}}
```